# Rails authentication issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to rails and right now I am developing a simple log in log out system.

In my app when I log in the URL generated is:

localhost:3000/user/index/7

When I log out I get back to the root. But if copy this URL and paste it in another browser window i get instantly logged in without being directed to the log in form. How to correct this issue.

I tried to store user id in session hash and then upon logout i have set user id in session to be nil. But that does not work. Help needed.

Edited:

In my Home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def signin
     user=User.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_login=? AND user_password=?",params[:user]     [:username],params[:user][:password]);

   if user!=nil
        session[:user_id]=user.user_id;
        redirect_to({:controller=>'user'})
   end

   end
end
```

In User controller i have a logout method:

```
def logout
   session[:user_id]=nil;
   redirect_to({:controller=>'home'});
end
```

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.root :controller => "home",:action => "index"
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Edited:

I have solved this issue I was not checking id value in session hash in User controller index method. But I have another question If i have an app in rails 2.3.17 and I want to shift it to latest version how much changes will I have to make

Comment: How do you implement the basic authentication?

Comment: In my home controller:

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.17 @Dogbert

Comment: You shouldn't be using outdated software. Please install Rails 3.2.13

Comment: I agree with @supernova32. You should be using Rails 3.2 or even Rails 4 if you're trying to learn the framework.

Comment: I have solved this issue I was not checking id value in session hash in User controller index method. But I have another question If i have an app in rails 2.3.17 and I want to shift it to latest version how much changes will I have to make.

Comment: please create a new question, or search around regarding the migration from Rails 2 to 3

Answer (score 1):

You can set before_filter for those actions in the controller. using that before_filter you can check session is nil or value is present.

Otherwise you can follow this railscasts video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the basic authentication. Once you get logged in, all your credentials are stored in the session headers which is maintained by the browser. If your clear your cache, then it should prompt for the password again....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. You can use `has_secure_password` inside your User model and generate a `sessions_controller` to handle the create and destroy. the methods are basically the same, but with the `has_secure_password` flag. You should then take care of destroying the session properly.

Comment: `has_secure_password` does nothing for the sessions. It only adds a few methods to authenticate a Model as long as it has a `password_digest` attribute. The developer is responsible for clearing out whatever session attribute was set to do the log in.

Comment: if you want to know more about the has_secure_password, I think this could help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend to use an existing authentication systems, like https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

On this site you can easily get an overview about other existing systems, and of there popularity and development activity.
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

You really don´t have to program such stuff by yourself, but if you really like to do it, maybe this could also helps you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised. But I recommend devise absolutely.

Comment: I love `devise` and it's a great gem, but for people that are just learning Rails, or Ruby for that matter, I wouldn't suggest jumping to using those at the beginning because it just tends to abstract all the things that are awesome about the framework/language. The Railscasts episode is great advice though.